# Consuming Google analytics.js events to custom endpoint

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

ok analytics.js is great. What would be even more great is the ability to not only send all data collected to Google Analytics, but also to a custom endpoint of choice so I can do anything I want with it.

Is this possible? If I had to guess somewhere in the analytics.js code it's just 1 changed line :). Oh btw: this may be aginst Google's T&A, no idea. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer the TOS question, but combining your own event reporting with GA should be fairly trivial. Couple of options.

1. Build your own function to send to a custom endpoint and GA.
2. Since function in javascript are objects too, you can wrap your own method around the ga code.

Example Below:

```
var oldGA = ga;
function ga(){
  if(arguments[0] == 'send' && arguments[1] == 'event') {
    // My code here
  }
  oldGA.call(arguments);
}
```

Comment: where `ga` is what? `window.ga` as set by Google analytics?

Comment: `ga` is the function set up by universal analytics in the global space. Should be the same as `window.ga`